# Remove Columns in Nifi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I'm trying to remove the last 16 of 18 columns from a Flowfile with CSV-formatted text. I thought my regex pattern would work, but the output is the exact same as the original data. My log doesn't show anything because it thinks it applied the rule correctly, so something must be wrong with my regex. I've included two images below of my flow and the ReplaceText Processor attributes I have set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace all (both) `.*` with `[^,]*`

Comment: This partially worked, but got me to the answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes we don't have control over what kind of data NiFi will receive (eg. column sequence may change) and if regex fails to process so does the downstream pipeline, I would say try with ConvertRecord, where RecordReader will have schema for 18 columns and RecordWriter will have schema for 2 columns. So if your data doesn't have those 2 columns or changed column sequence/position, then the data will still get validated/converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: I'm not sure if it was my grouping pattern not working or what, but I changed the .* to [,]* and made two separate groups for each of the first two columns, then a group of (.*) for the rest of the columns

```
^((?:[^,]*,))((?:[^,]*))((.*))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use Record based processing I would suggest that it will be better to use QueryRecord and select only the needed columns using that processor. Doing complex regex is painful for maintainence imo.

The sql for the QueryRecord processor will be:

```
SELECT column_header1, column_header2 FROM FLOWFILE
```